# Transit Travel Mode in Google Maps Android API

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create a Map activity which would take source and destination locations in two edit text controls and would return a map in transit mode BUS only showing the route along with the distance.I am not an expert at programming so detailed explanations are welcome.

Comment: have you found any solutions?